# Should search whole table and give data in one row according to the condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with values as follows:

```
AC_NO  INV_NO   CC      FT
--------------------------------
1      A        PTN     INVOICE
1      A        PTN     BDE
2      B        ABC     INVOICE
2      B        PTN     INVOICE
2      B        PTN     BDE
```

```
SELECT
ac_no,
CASE  
WHEN FT like '%INVOICE%' THEN 'AVAILABLE' else 'NOTAVAILABLE'
END AS INVOICE ,
CASE  
WHEN FT like '%BDE%' THEN 'AVAILABLE' else 'NOTAVAILABLE'
END AS BDE
FROM Account_info where CC='PTN';
```

```
Output 
------------------------------------
1   A   Available      Notavailable
1   A   Notavailable   Available
2   B   Available      Notavailable
2   B   Notavailable   Available
```

but I need them in the following  format:

```
AC_NO   INVOICE       BDE
--------------------------------
1       AVAILABLE     AVAILABLE
2       AVAILABLE     AVAILABLE
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: You select three columns and your output shows four :-) In your sample table data `AC_NO` and `INV_NO` always match (1=A, 2=B). But as there should be no redundance in a database table, I surmise that in real data, we could also find records with 1=B and 2=A. And for the result we can ignore `INV_NO` completely. You are only interested in the each `INV_NO` and whether at least one entry for it is "AVAILABLE" for invoice resp. BDE. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use `MAX ( CASE )` and `GROUP BY` along with `COALESCE` or `NVL`

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ba46a/6)

**Query 1**:

```
  SELECT ac_no,
         COALESCE (MAX (CASE WHEN FT =  'INVOICE' THEN 'AVAILABLE' END),
                   'NOTAVAILABLE')
            AS INVOICE,
         COALESCE (MAX (CASE WHEN FT = 'BDE' THEN 'AVAILABLE' END),
                   'NOTAVAILABLE')
            AS BDE
    FROM Account_info
   WHERE CC = 'PTN'
GROUP BY ac_no
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ba46a/6/0)**:

```
| AC_NO |   INVOICE |       BDE |
|-------|-----------|-----------|
|     1 | AVAILABLE | AVAILABLE |
|     2 | AVAILABLE | AVAILABLE |
```